# Convert my date format in PHP

Tags: date, format

I have to convert the format of this date from 2012-11-03CET21: 00:00 +0100 to 21:00 - 03/11/2012
How can I do that?

The underlying string print "2012-11-03CET21: 00:00 +0100"

```
$start_date = date($values['start_time'] );
echo $start_date;
```

but I wish it were so 21:00 - 03/11/2012

Answer (score 0):

```
$myval = "2012-11-03CET21:00:00 +0100";
$start_date = date("H:i - d/m/Y", strtotime($myval)-3600);
echo $start_date;
```